# Maximizing Parallelepiped Spanned by Vectors

Tags: optimization, vectors

I have to find $k$ to maximize the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors $A = (6,k,0), B = (3,4,-k)$ and $C = (1,2,2)$.

I know the volume would just be $f(x)= ABC$ and that I take the triple scalar product to get the parallelepiped spanned by those vectors, but would I use LaGrange to maximize?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Compute volume as the triple scalar product, as a function of $k$, to get $V(k)$, and then since $V: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ you can use ordinary calculus.

Moreover, since $V$ is a low-degree polynomial in $k$, basic algebra could be enough :)

**UPDATE**

In view of the comment, you get
$$
\begin{split}
V(k) 
&= (6,k,0) \cdot (3,4,-k) \times (1,2,2) \\
&= \det
   \begin{bmatrix}
   6 & k & 0 \\
   3 & 4 & -k \\
   1 & 2 & 2
   \end{bmatrix} \\
&= 6 \det \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -k \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
 - k \det \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -k \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\\
&= 6(8+2k)-k(6+k)\\
&= 48 + 12k - 6k - k^2 \\
&= 48 + 6k -k^2
\end{split}
$$
which is a basic parabola facing down, so the maximum occurs at $$k = \frac{-b}{2a} = \frac{-6}{2 \cdot (-1)} = 3$$ with maximum volume of $$V(3) = 48 + 18-9=57.$$

Comment: That polynomial is -- after non-trivial factorisation -- $(x^2-6x-48)^2$, what's beyond basic algebra.  From here $x=3$ is the maximum.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe see the update -- a trivial algebraic problem requiring no calculus whatsoever. In addition, your polynomial is wrong because it has no maxima, just a minimum...